# How to check that a random variable is in $L^p(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral

How to check that a random variable is in $L^p(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$?

Maybe I should provide an example to get my point across.

Let $X_\alpha$ be a random variable with CFD $F_\alpha(x) = (1 - \frac{1}{x^\alpha})\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty]}(x)$

I want to find for which values $\alpha$ $X_\alpha$ belongs to $L^p$. 
Should I look at integrating the density function to the power p in absolute value or rather the CFD? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_\alpha$ is nonnegative, so it suffices to check $E X_\alpha^p < \infty$.

Since you have the CDF, it is easiest to use the tail sum probability for this expectation.

$$E X_\alpha^p = \int_0^\infty P(X_\alpha^p > t) \, dt = \int_0^\infty (1 - F_\alpha(t^{1/p})) \, dt.$$

Hopefully this helps you finish the question.

Comment: What happened to $p$ in the last expression?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: What if the sign $X_\alpha$ is not known?

Comment: @qcc101 The CDF you gave implies $X_\alpha \ge 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes, I mean: what if in another case I do not know the sign of my random variable?

Comment: @qcc101 I'm not sure what you are asking, but you would have to show $E|X_\alpha|^p < \infty$ some other way, using whatever information about $X_\alpha$ that you have...